# Help with proof of theorem 1-10 spivak calculus on manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> **Theorem 1-10** The bounded function (mapping to $\mathbb{R}$), $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if the oscillation of a point of $f$ at $a$ is $0$

The definition spivak provides of oscillation given is (where $o(f,a)$ is oscillation of $f$ at $a$ where $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$: $$o(f,a)=\lim_{\delta\to0}[\displaystyle \sup \left\{ f(x):x\in A :\left\vert x-a\right\vert < \delta \right\}-\displaystyle \inf \left\{ f(x):x\in A :\vert x-a\vert < \delta \right\}]$$
Spivak shorthands the 
$$M(a,f,\delta)=\sup \left\{ f(x):x\in A :\left\vert x-a\right\vert < \delta \right\}$$
$$m(a,f,\delta)=\inf \left\{ f(x):x\in A :\left\vert x-a\right\vert < \delta \right\}$$
I know how to prove this theorem when assumed $f$ is continuous but I cannot prove the converse. Any help to show equivalence to epsilon-delta?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that the oscillation is $0$. We want to prove that $f$ is continuous at $a$, i.e. we want to show that

> for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - a| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(a)| \le \epsilon.$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, and let $\delta$ be such that $$M(a,f,\delta) - m(a,f,\delta) \le \epsilon.$$ Then for any $x$ such that $|x - a| < \delta$ we have:$$-\epsilon \le m(a,f,\delta) - M(a,f,\delta) \le f(x) - f(a) \le M(a,f,\delta) - m(a,f,\delta) \le \epsilon.$$
The same reasoning can be applied to get the same estimate with $f(a) - f(x)$ and hence $$|f(x) - f(a)| \le \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $\omicron(f,x)=\lim\limits_{\delta\to 0^+}\sup\{|f(z)-f(y)|:z,y\in B_\delta(x)\}$ and all will be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. If $o(f,a) = 0$, then there must be a $\delta$ such that $M(a,f,\delta) = m(a,f,\delta) < \varepsilon$. So what does that tell you about $|f(x) - f(a)|$, when $|x - a| < \delta$?